# Barplot of the cumulative frequency of events on different dates

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, frequency

I have a set of dates and events, something like:

```
1990-01-01 A
1990-01-01 B
1990-01-01 C
1990-01-02 A
1990-01-03 A
1990-01-03 C
1990-01-04 B
```

I want to make a bar plot, with date on the x-axis and the height of the bars representing the cumulative frequency of each event on each date.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
# Generate data
set.seed(23)
t <- c(rep("1990-01-01", 10), rep("1990-01-02", 10))
v <- sample(c("A","B","C"), 20, replace=TRUE)

# Side-by-side barplot
quartz()
barplot(t(apply(table(v,t),1,cumsum)), beside=T, col=c("purple", "darkblue", "skyblue"))
legend("topleft", legend=c("A", "B", "C"), col=c("purple", "darkblue", "skyblue"), pch=15)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I need them stacked (beside = F); also, I want them to be cumulative through time: if there are 2, 2, 6 of A, B, C in time 1, in time 2 it should be 4, 6, 10 and so on (I'm basing on the numbers on your graph).

Comment: I edited to make the sums cumulative, but I did not stack the bars because it looks terrible.